# Compilation Error When Trying to Write a Servlet to Insert HTML Form Data into a Database

Tags: java

I'm getting a minor compilation error trying to write a servlet and I've checked all the {} and ;

Here is the code:

```
//This servlet processes the user's registration and redirects them to the catalog.

// Load required libraries
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseAccess extends HttpServlet{

// JDBC driver name and database URL
private static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
private static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dvdsite";

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException

      //  Database credentials
      static final String USER = "user";
      static final String PASS = "";

      // Get form values from register page
      String username = request.getParameter("username");
      int userID = Integer.parseInt(username);
      String password = request.getParameter("password");
      String email = request.getParameter("email");
{
      try {
         // Register JDBC driver
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

         // Open a connection
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

         // Execute SQL query
         stmt = conn.createStatement();
         String sql;
         sql = "INSERT INTO dvdsite values (username, password, email)";
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

         // Clean-up environment
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //Handle errors for JDBC
         se.printStackTrace();
      }catch(Exception e){
         //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         //finally block used to close resources
         try{
            if(stmt!=null)
               stmt.close();
         }catch(SQLException se2){
         }// nothing we can do
         try{
            if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
         }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
         }//end finally try
      } //end try
   }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting: 1 error found:
File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/register.java  [line: 18]
Error: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/register.java:18: ';' expected

The errors comes up on this line:

throws ServletException, IOException

Can anyone help?

Comment: Method bodies must have braces.

Comment: Can you post `register.java` class?

Comment: stick a { after IOException

Comment: @Tom, I tried that and it just gave me more errors. :-(

Comment: the error comes in register.java, where is it?

Comment: This is the register.java file.

Comment: The error message doesn't fit to your code. You are only using standard Java things. There is nothing here triggering any "register.java". What do you do to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this version with fixed syntax errors. And call the file `DatabaseAccess.java` because files need to be named like their classes.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DatabaseAccess extends HttpServlet {

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dvdsite";

    // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "user";
    static final String PASS = "";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Get form values from register page
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        int userID = Integer.parseInt(username);
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");

        Connection conn;
        Statement stmt;

        try {
            // Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            // Open a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            // Execute SQL query
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "INSERT INTO dvdsite values (username, password, email)";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            // Clean-up environment
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            // Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }// nothing we can do
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }// end finally try
        } // end try
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just gave me more errors. This is so frustrating!

Comment: @TonySmith Try it again. I fixed it completely now. Two variable declarations were still missing.